# deep copy of vector in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

In AS3, we can copy Array in two ways:

```
newArr = oldArr.concat();
```

or

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeObject(oldArr);
ba.position = 0;
newArr = ba.readObject() as Array;
```

But these two ways don't work with Vector when I need to copy a Vector with complex data type.Just like `Vector.<Point>`.When I use ByteArray to copy a Vector with complex data type, the compiler says the new Vector I copy the old one to is null.

Answer (score 3):

Register a class alias with `flash.net.registerClassAlias` before writing your object to the `ByteArray`, e.g.:

```
var points:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>();
var pointsCloned:Vector.<Point>;
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Point", Point);

points.push(new Point(1, 2));
points.push(new Point(3, 4));
points.push(new Point(5, 6));

ba.writeObject(points);
ba.position = 0;
pointsCloned = ba.readObject() as Vector.<Point>;

trace(points);
trace(pointsCloned);
```

Thanks to this [blog post](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2009/02/10/easy-deep-clone-method-for-actionscript-30/)!

Comment: Oh, it works well.Thanks! But why can it works just after register a class alias?

Comment: @Piggyi You can find a short explanation in the [ActionScript 3.0 Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/common/langref/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29). That's everything I know, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [`.map()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#map%28%29), something like:

```
function pointCloner(item:Point, index:int, vector:Vector.<Point>):Point {
    return item.clone();
}

var newVector:Vector.<Point> = oldVector.map(pointCloner);
```